# What are the consequences of high costs?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a typical NN multiclassifier (10 classes) with one hidden layer. The training and test costs do not minimize as much as they do with added layers, however the accuracy of the classifier is the same in both networks (91% training, 88% testing).

The test data is separate from the train data.

What are the consequences of the cost values being high (0.5 training, 0.7 testing) when the training is ceased?

Why might the accuracies be the same despite high costs in the first network?

Happy to provide more information if required.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question implicitly requires answering a lot of other questions as you will see later:

> What are the consequences of the cost values being high (0.5 training,
>   0.7 testing) when the training is ceased?

First of all, deciding whether some cost value is high or not is subjective, that is there is no real threshold, however, cost value is a good indicator of overfitting/underfitting in the model. Thus, it's better to compare the cost between the training set and the test set as follows:

- Training Cost is noticeably less than Test Cost and Training cost is relatively small: That probably indicates the existence of overfitting (a.k.a overestimation or high variance).
- Training Cost is noticeably high and Test Cost value is close to Training cost value: That probably indicates the existence of underfitting (a.k.a underestimation or high bias).

Now bear with me, overfitting/underfitting also related to the hidden layers and hidden units in NN!! (see next).

---

Secondly, the number of hidden layers and the number of hidden units directly affect the cost value as it changes the training complexity as follows (*from Introduction to Neural Networks for Java (second edition) by Jeff Heaton*):

Number of Hidden Layers:

- **0** only capable of representing linear separable functions or decisions.
- **1** can approximate any function that contains a continuous mapping
  from one finite space to another.
- **2** can represent an arbitrary decision boundary to arbitrary accuracy
  with rational activation functions and can approximate any smooth
  mapping to **any accuracy**.

On the other hand, using too few neurons in the hidden layers will result in underfitting, whereas using too many neurons in the hidden layers may result in overfitting, as a rule of thumb:

- The number of hidden neurons should be between the size of the input layer and the size of the output layer.
- The number of hidden neurons should be 2/3 the size of the input layer, plus the size of the output layer.
- The number of hidden neurons should be less than twice the size of the input layer.

That was in summary the relationship between the cost values of training-set and test-set and with the hidden layers size in NN.

So the  consequences are overfitting / underfitting.

---

> Why might the accuracies be the same despite high costs in the first
>   network?

That's a bit weird as it's an inverse relationship between cost and accuracy, that's the lower the cost the higher the accuracy.

However, it's unclear what accuracy you mean, because as I see, you're testing the accuracy on the training set which is pointless, but look again at your result, they reflect the inverse relation between cost and accuracy as mentioned above:

```
0.5 training cost -> 91% training accuracy
0.7 test cost -> 88% test accuracy
```

---

If you still have any doubts, please provide the architecture of your NN and the dataset in addition to in-details results of accuracy and costs in a nice summarized form.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth post. I think the issue is knowing whether I'm overfitting or not. If we only consider a 1-hidden-layer NN with 784 inputs, plotting the test-train cost graphs show extremely close correlation (underfitting) with very small number (4) of neurons and an accuracy of 70%. That's straightforward. Though the graphs of 16 neurons vs ~500 neurons are similar in shape (divergent but still descreasing), with marginal accuracy improvements and lower costs.

Comment: Secondly, I see that Heaton recommends neurons = 2/3 * inputs + output. Do you know of reasoning for this? It doesn't say in the book. I will accept your answer soon. Thanks.